# Trouble with getting statistics on rolling a natural yahtzee in C

Tags: c

I am making this program for an assignment at school, however we need to get the highest number of rolls it takes to obtain a Yahtzee and the lowest number of rolls it takes to get a Yahtzee. Then we need to find the average number of rolls. At the moment I am kind of confused on where I went wrong with determining the highest and lowest number of rolls to obtain a Yahtzee. Can anyone help me out, I would greatly appreciate it. The program runs until 100 natural Yahtzees are obtained.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <limits.h>

int main( void )
{  // MARKS THE BEGINNING OF THE main( ) BLOCK OF STATEMENTS

int die1 = 0 , die2 = 0 , die3 = 0 , die4 = 0, die5 = 0 , roll = 0 ;
int lownr = INT_MAX , highnr = 0 , yahtzee = 0 , averagenr;
int roll_total = 0 ;
srandom ( (unsigned) time (NULL) ) ; 

printf( "\nWelcome User, this program demonstrates the " ) ;
printf( "number of rolls it takes to obtain" ) ; 
printf( "\na natural Yahtzee.\n" ) ;

die1 = random ( ) % 6 + 1;
die2 = random ( ) % 6 + 1;
die3 = random ( ) % 6 + 1;
die4 = random ( ) % 6 + 1;
die5 = random ( ) % 6 + 1;

printf( "\nYou rolled: %d, %d, %d, %d, %d.\n\n" , die1 ,
         die2 , die3 , die4 , die5 ) ;

while (yahtzee < 100) {

++roll;
++roll_total;

die1 = random ( ) % 6 + 1;
die2 = random ( ) % 6 + 1;
die3 = random ( ) % 6 + 1;
die4 = random ( ) % 6 + 1;
die5 = random ( ) % 6 + 1;


if ((die1==die2) && (die2==die3) && (die3==die4) && (die4==die5)) {

yahtzee = yahtzee +1;

    /* If you have yahtzee, compare roll with previous values of highnr/lownr */
    if (roll>highnr)
        highnr = roll;
    if (roll<lownr)
        lownr = roll;

    /* Reset the roll counter, for next yahtzee */
    roll = 0;
    }

    }
    averagenr = roll_total / yahtzee ;


    printf("\n The total number of yahtzees you rolled is: %d.",yahtzee);
    printf("\n The total number of times you rolled is: %d.",roll_total);
    printf("\n The highest number of rolls to get a yahtzee is: %d",highnr);
    printf("\n The lowest number of rolls to get a yahtzee is: %d", lownr);
    printf("\n The average number of rolls to obtain a yahtzee is: %d", 
       averagenr);
    printf ( "\n\n Thank you for using this program. " ) ;
    printf ( "GoodBye.\n\n " ) ;

    return ( 0 ) ;

    }
```

Sample Output

```
Welcome User, this program demonstrates the number of rolls it takes to obtain
a natural Yahtzee.

You rolled: 5, 5, 3, 2, 1.


The total number of yahtzees you rolled is: 100.
The total number of times you rolled is: 116704.
The highest number of rolls to get a yahtzee is: 5284
The lowest number of rolls to get a yahtzee is: 18
The average number of rolls to obtain a yahtzee is: 1167

Thank you for using this program. GoodBye.
```

**SOLVED**

Comment: You may need to start your roll counter at `1`. Might want to take a second look at your other variables too. IE `highnr` can start at zero, but `lownr` cannot.

Comment: On my compiler it is giving error about `srandom` and `random`. Don't you think it should be `srand` and `rand`?

Comment: @haccks Back in the days when `rand` was disappointingly predictable, BSD added a second random number generator with more internal state. `random` and `srandom` are the almost-`rand`/`srand`-compatible front end to that other random number generator, which is still available today on sufficiently BSD-ish systems (including glibc with `-D_BSD_SOURCE`)

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley; Thanks for the information. Never knew that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, the key is that you need to make use of two counters for the number of rolls. One for the total number of rolls, which you will later use to compute the average and one that you use to keep track of the current number of rolls towards the next yahtzee.

```
int roll=0, roll_total=0;
int lownr=INT_MAX, highnr=0, averagenr;

while(yahtzee < 100) {

    ++roll; /* This will keep track of the number of rolls towards next yahtzee */
    ++roll_total; /* This is total number of rolls in entire program */

    if ((die1==die2) && (die2==die3) && (die3==die4) && (die4==die5)) {

        yahtzee = yahtzee +1;

        /* If you have yahtzee, compare roll with previous values of highnr/lownr */
        if (roll>highnr)
            highnr = roll;
        if (roll<lownr)
            lownr = roll;

        /* Reset the roll counter, for next yahtzee */
        roll = 0;
    }
}

averagenr = roll_total / yahtzee ;
```

**EDIT**

I answered your comment with another comment, but code in comments gets unreadable, so I will help you a bit more. Carefully look at the updated code and remove these lines from your code:

```
lownr = roll;
highnr = roll;
```

Comment: thanks, but I also need to define yahtzee too which is why I have the if statement for if dice1==dice2......etc.

Comment: @Nick You already have that code; this is showing you what you don't have.

Comment: Exactly, the above is not a full solution, but you have to implement my changes in what you already have. The key to your problem is the *two separate* counters

Comment: @pankrates ok I will test it out and correct my code, and display the output I get.

Comment: @pankrates still having issues, I updated my code with your suggestions.

Comment: Ok several things go wrong. With my `if(yahtzee)` conditional I was just writing shorthand for your yahtzee condition, use `(die1==die2) && (die2==die3) && (die3==die4) && (die4==die5)` and get rid of the second conditional. Also look at how I initialize `lownr` and `highnr`, very important. Remove all the initializations for those variables that you had

Comment: INT_MAX isn't working for me. int lownr=INT_MAX; gives me an error saying 'INT_MAX' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: include the header file `#include <limits.h>`

Comment: @Pankrates updated my code, the low roll seems a bit too low what do you think? Everything else seems to be working now.

Comment: Well too low in your words means "you would not expect yahtzee so soon" but since its random it is entirely possible. Just run the program a couple of times (seeding the random number generator differently each time!) and you will probably get larger numbers as well

Comment: @Pankrates, yeah thank you so much for your help. You are a life saver. Everything works perfectly now!

Comment: Good to hear. If you are satisfied with the answer it is good practive to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)